# Getting error while setting speechRecognition.startListenenig() and pass the intent

Tags: java, android

I get error when I set `SPR.startlistenening()` method I want to use continuously speech recognition and perform tasks based on results.
I am making an app that countinuously uses speech recognition and do specific task on results:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setSPR();
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,1);
    SPR.startListening(intent);

}
private void setSPR() {
    if (SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this)){
        SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        SPR.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEndOfSpeech() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
                ArrayList<String> results = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                setRecognitionResults(results.get(0));
            }
            @Override
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {           }
        });
    }
}
```

Error >>>

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.speech.SpeechRecognizer.startListening(android.content.Intent)'
>   on a null object reference at
>   com.teamdev.talkingtorch.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:74) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1341)
>   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7278) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)

Comment: post the error you are getting

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.speech.SpeechRecognizer.startListening(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
        at com.teamdev.talkingtorch.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:74)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1341)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)